# MVC in Android: Application or Service for asynchronous updates?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, service

(I'm sorry for not being so clear in my first post)

Here is the situation: I have data that is to be refreshed from the Internet. Let's call it `Model`.

**What I want to do:** Basically it sounds like an MVC model, where the `Model` is also kept persistent in local (private) storage. The `Model` and its associated methods are application-wise. There are several `Activity`'s that display and manipulate different aspects of it:

- User
  navigates across different `Activity`'s
  that display `Model`
  from different perspectives. Currently I have a `ListActivity` for all elements, and an `Activity` for one element's details
- Sometimes `Model` needs refreshing.
  Surely this is done on a different thread. Refreshing can be triggered from several `Activity`'s.
- There are several (time consuming) common 
  tasks that can be triggered from different `Activity`'s
- My application loads and saves `Model`
  to private storage when it starts
  and stops

**My problem:** I'm not sure where to put `Model` and the related tasks in. Also, I don't know what mechanism to use to notify `Activity`'s. Currently I come up with 2 approaches:

- Use `Service` and send broadcasts. Saving to disk is performed in `Service#onDestroyed()`, so I want to minimize that by binding it to `Activity`'s. At this point, I'm also not sure how to deliver the updated information: whether to provide a *getter* in `Binder`, or include that in the broadcast message.
- Customize the `Application` object so that *refreshing methods* and *getters* are available globally. I then perform update from `Activity`'s using `AsyncTask`. If there are other `Activity`'s that are behind the current `Activity`, they will update in `onResume()` when the user navigates back.

Reasons I'm not using a class with static methods:

- I need to save and store `Model` to disk.
- Some of the methods need a Context
  for displaying toasts, notifications, caching, etc.

Also, I don't put these functionalities in an `Activity` because there are several activities that manipulate the same piece of persistent data.

Below are pseudocode illustrating what I mean:

**Using Service:**

```
/** Service maintaining state and performing background tasks */
class MyService extends Service {
    Model mModel;
    Binder mBinder;

    onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mBinder = new Binder();
        // load mModel from disk, or do default initialization
    }

    onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // save mModel to disk
    }

    onBind() {
        return mBinder;
    }

    class Binder {
        refresh() {
            new AsyncTask() {
                doInBackground() {
                    // update mModel from Internet
                }
                onPostExecute() {
                    sendBroadcasts(new Intent("my.package.REFRESHED"));
                }
            }.execute();
        }

        getState() {
            return mModel.getState();
        }
    }
}

/** Activity displaying result */
class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    MyService.Binder mBinder;

    onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register mReceiver
        // bind service
    }

    onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // unbind service
        // unregister mReceiver
    }

    /** Invokes time-consuming update */
    refresh() {
        // binding is asynchronous, and user may trigger refreshing too early
        if (mBinder != null) {
            mBinder.refresh();
        }
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        onReceive(Intent intent) {
            if ("my.package.REFRESHED".equals(intent.getAction())
                    && mBinder != null) {
                updateViews(mBinder.getState());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Make the functionality globally accessible in the custom Application object**

```
/** Custom Application providing domain specific functionalities */
class MyApplication extends Application {
    Model mModel;

    onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // load mModel from disk, or do default initialization
    }

    onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        // save mModel to disk
    }

    void refresh() {
        /** time-consuming */
    }

    getState() {
        return mModel.getState();
    }
}

/** Activity displaying result */
class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // in case some top Activities have refreshed
        // and user is navigating back
        updateViews(((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getState());
    }

    /** Invokes time-consuming update */
    refresh() {
        new AsyncTask() {
            doInBackground() {
                ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).refresh();
            }
            onPostExecute() {
                // update the ListView according to result
                updateViews(((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getState());
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Weaknesses I can think of for the `Service` approach is complexity, since Binding is asynchronous. And it's very likely that I have to repeat some code because I have both `ListActivity` and `Activity`

For the `Application` approach, the documentation says not to rely on `onTerminate()` being called.

I know I'm being very awkward. What is the conventional way to solve this sort of problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Service`s are mostly suitable for something that is not bound to a single `Activity` (and usually work together with `NotificationManager` or a `Widget`). This doesn't seem to be the case.
So my suggestion is to have a well-engineered `AsyncTask` that manages state via `SharedPreferences`/`SQLite` itself (instead of abusing `Applicaion`) and will be launched from the `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could extend a BroadcastReceiver instead of a Service, and when it's done doing what it needs to do, it loads up an Activity with the results.

Comment: It was my fault for not being clear. I have several Activities that access and mutate the same piece of application-wise data :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain what kind of info are you getting but this line is important:

> These tasks involve states that need
>   to be loaded and saved gracefully when
>   the application starts and stops

If that is the case, why don't you do an `AsynTask` inside the `Activity`?

I had your same worries about sending `Intents` with `ArrayList` inside but I have an app which does exactly that and I am not having performance issues.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I didn't put that in an Activity because I have several Activities that access and mutate the same piece of application-wise data. I editted my post.